# Sharepoint 2016 File Checkout and file check in Java

Tags: 2016

I am trying to check out and checking file using rest api, but getting 400 Bad Request.

## Following is my code:

```
String urlM = "https://sharepoint.com/sites//_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/Project%20Logs/My%20Cust/11111/aa/Test%20Folder/filDetails.txt')/CheckOut()";

        System.out.println("urlM    " + urlM);
        System.out.println("urlM    " + urlM);
        URL urlMkt = new URL(urlM);
        URLConnection conMkt = urlMkt.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConMkt = (HttpURLConnection) conMkt;
        httpConMkt.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConMkt.setDoInput(true);
        httpConMkt.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConMkt.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);

if (httpConMkt.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            respStrMkt = "Market Folder has been created successfully. ResponseCode : " + httpConMkt.getResponseCode();
        } else {
            respStrMkt += "Error while creating Market Folder ResponseCode : " + httpConMkt.getResponseCode() + " "
                    + httpConMkt.getResponseMessage();
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you have the **X-RequestDigest** header.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your response. Iam passing the token. the x-requestdigest is not required. Also I have got the solution. Instead of String urlM = "https://sharepoint.com/sites//_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/Project%20Logs/My%20Cust/11111/aa/Test%20Folder/filDetails.txt')/CheckOut()";
i put as "String urlM = "https://sharepoint.com/sites//_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/Project%20Logs/My%20Cust/11111/aa/Test%20Folder')File /(filDetails.txt')/CheckOut()"; and its working now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. Iam passing the token. the x-requestdigest is not required. Also I have got the solution. Instead of String urlM = "sharepoint.com/sites//_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/…"; i put as "String urlM = "sharepoint.com/sites//_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/… /(filDetails.txt')/CheckOut()"; and its working now